# Apache Camel: using compound conditions in when()

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel DSL route and want to check if the body is not `null` and body does not contains substring like `authenticate failed`. In java something like:

```
              if(body != null && !body.contains("authenticate failed")) {
                  //Do something.
                  
              }
```

Apache Camel DSL:

```
    .choice()
        .when(body().contains("authenticate failed"))
             .log("after choice body().contains('authenticate failed') body: ${body}")
        .when(body().isNotNull()) //Here I want to add the addiontional condition to this when `body not contains authenticate failed`.
```

How can I write a condition like this?  predicates objects in the process method and write tin my case?

Comment: You can use `Predicate` built with `PredicateBuilder` (cfr https://camel.apache.org/manual/predicate.html)

Comment: @TacheDeChoco: This worked for me: `.when(simple("${body} != null && ${body} not contains 'authenticate failed'"))`

Comment: If you use the predicate approach. I need to access the body from the route. So do I need to create the predicate for example in the process method. Somethig like that:         .process(new Processor() {
   @Override
   public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    Message message = exchange.getIn();
    Predicate p1 = body().isNotNull();
    Predicate p2 = body().isNotEqualTo("authenticate failed");
    Predicate predicate_result = PredicateBuilder.and(p1, p2);
    message.setHeader("predicate_result", predicate_result);
    
   } 
  })

Comment: @TacheDeChoco: How can I write instead of `body().isNotEqualTo("authenticate failed")` the following 'body does not contains 'authenticate failed'' with the predicate approach? body().contains is avialable but no method for .notContains()

Comment: Simply surround your test with the not(...) function of the PredicateBuilder (https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-support/latest/org/apache/camel/support/builder/PredicateBuilder.html#not(org.apache.camel.Predicate))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PredicateBuilder to create pretty composite predicates. Here's example how to do simple Body is not null or empty check with PredicateBuilder.

```java
package com.example;

import org.apache.camel.Predicate;
import org.apache.camel.RoutesBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.builder.PredicateBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ExampleTests extends CamelTestSupport {
    

    @Test
    public void testValidBody() throws Exception {

        MockEndpoint resultMockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:notNull");
        resultMockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);

        template.sendBody("direct:predicateExample", "Hello world!");

        resultMockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Test
    public void testEmptyBody() throws Exception {


        MockEndpoint resultMockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:nullOrEmpty");
        resultMockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);

        template.sendBody("direct:predicateExample", null);

        resultMockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Test
    public void testNullBody() throws Exception {

        MockEndpoint resultMockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:nullOrEmpty");
        resultMockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);

        template.sendBody("direct:predicateExample", null);

        resultMockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
             
                Predicate bodyNotNullOrEmpty = PredicateBuilder.and(
                    body().isNotNull(), 
                    body().isNotEqualTo("")
                );

                from("direct:predicateExample")
                    .routeId("predicateExample")
                    .choice().when(bodyNotNullOrEmpty)
                        .log("Received body: ${body}")
                        .to("mock:notNull")
                    .otherwise()
                        .log("Body was null or empty!")
                        .to("mock:nullOrEmpty")
                    .end()
                    .log("done");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Not and Or can take lists of predicates as arguments or even other composite predicates which allows one to make some fairly complex composite predicates. However when using PredicateBuilder starts to get overly verbose it's good to just use processor or bean instead to abstract away some of the complexity.

Comment: Östermann: could you please take a look at this question and tell me what I am doing wrong. I have created the PredicateBuilder as you suggested but I am still getting into the first when block of the choice function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72226796/apache-camel-compound-conditions-by-using-the-predicatebuilder-and-access-them

Comment: If I initialize my PredicateBuilder outside the form as in your example it works. How can I do it from the process method as in my linked question in my comment above?